# Getting an error when executing npm command

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

I freshly installed nodejs 14 with nvm on a Ubuntu 20.04 machine.
When I try to run a simple `npm install` command, I get the following error:

```
Error: Failed to replace env in config: ${FAST_HTTPAUTH}
at /home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.0/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:415:13
at String.replace (<anonymous>)
at envReplace (/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.0/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:411:12)
at parseField (/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.0/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:389:7)
at /home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.0/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:330:24
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at Conf.add (/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.0/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:328:23)
at ConfigChain.addString (/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/config-chain/index.js:244:8)
at Conf.<anonymous> (/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.0/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:316:10)
at /home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:123:16
```

/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.0/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:59
throw new Error('npm.load() required')

```
Error: npm.load() required
at Object.get (/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.0/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:59:13)
at process.errorHandler (/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.0/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/error-handler.js:208:32)
at process.emit (events.js:315:20)
at process._fatalException (internal/process/execution.js:156:25)
```

Has anyone experienced this before and can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are in scout24 specific environment and you need to setup your FAST credentials in env variables. Look for FAST in docs.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.